# Windows Forms, Right To Left Layout BG Image not showing

Tags: c#, winforms, right-to-left

I have a Right To Left layout applied to my form. And there is a form, which has a background image, and it is not showing up when RightToLeft is true. What's the Problem  ? Thanks

Comment: Background Image with Right To Left layout is not supported.

Comment: So what is the alternate way Hassan ?

Comment: Add a Panel dynamically and set its background image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.righttoleftlayout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

For the `Form.RightToLeftLayout` Property:

> BackgroundImage, Opacity, TransparencyKey, and the painting events are not supported.

Workaround (After setting `RightToLeftlayout = true` add a Panel and set its background image):

```
this.RightToLeftLayout = true;
Panel pnl = new Panel();
pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
pnl.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("D:\\background.png");
pnl.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;   
this.Controls.Add(pnl);
pnl.SendToBack();
```

Comment: thank you, one more question, what mean after layout change Hassan ?

Comment: setting `RightToLeftLayout = true` :)

Comment: Hey Hassan, can you offer an alternate way to do that ? :/ Because I am having other problems with that panel. Is there another way you can offer for solving this problem ?

Comment: What kind of issues you are facing? See `Hans` answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400167/righttoleft-property-in-form-in-c-sharp-updated).

Comment: I have this problem. When I override OnPaintBackground , each control that is on the form is having the same background, which the Form has, but I only need to draw background of the Form :/ how solve that ?